# Routing issue from Wizard tab page to normal page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-wizard

i am getting a problem when i am trying to get back from wizard tab page to normal page whose url are competely differnt.My first page url is like localhost:8080/#/firstpage?aparam=#abcd&bparam=45564.Then my second page will have four wizard tabs A,B,C,D with back and continue buttons.I wrote a logic for second page to go to  first page using "Back" button in first A tab like

```
if(tab0ne==true){
    $scope.tabone=false;
    $state.go('firstpage')
}
```

For refreshing logic i defined $rootScope==undefined
when i refresh and reload the second wizard page and then click back button then its displaying the same localhost:8080/#/secondpage even though its entering into that if block its not changing to first page.Please let me know if any one know the solution for this problem

Comment: For me the most confusing in this story is _i defined $rootScope==undefined_... Can you share states definition and controllers of mentioned views from your app? Best to be reproduced in jsfiddle/plunker

Comment: HI Slatin i have a second page with 4 multi step or wizard tab of one url sharing i defined some model in first page $rootScope.modeldd != undefined to get refresh and reload after refresh of second page after when i click back button its not going to first its staying in same page.But before refreshing that page if you click on back button its works its navigates to first page.